# Keep session alive after call $get mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session

I'm trying to keep alive session from angular with a $get, I'm using the following code

```
basic service method angular
keepAlive: function () {
            return $http.get('/util/KeepAlive');
        }, 


basic controller call service
basicFactory.keepAlive().success(function (data) {
            if (data.Estado) {
            }
        });

Controller MVC
[HttpGet]
public bool KeepAlive()
{
    return true;
}
```

In debug I can see the method is called, but the session time doesn't refresh and expires,
and if I refresh the page(f5) the time session is reset.

Why calling a get from angular the session expired and it doesn't update the session time? 
Now my config session is:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="5" />
```

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Can you replicate same problem by doing GET request from browser or Postman? Then AngularJS part isn't relevant at all.

Comment: the problem is that the timeout doesn't change after I do a get or a post, it's strange because if I refresh the page then this timeout is reset to 5 minutes, I want the same behavior with my get request.

Comment: And your'e right, AngularJS part isn't relevant at all. it's only the way that I'm doing the request.

Comment: I'd suggest then to eliminate AngularJS part from the question since it's irrelevant and provide more details on server side. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Took off angularjs tag since it shouldn't be relevant as mentioned the session timing out is happening server side.  I have similar code in my server side when regular requests come in to extend the session time based on the last request that came in with authorization info and using angular on the client side, not doing anything special in the client to extend the session though since it's basically up to the server to keep that session info somewhere (file db or otherwise)

Comment: Check if the browser is taking the page from caché